# Preserving proportions when adding to a selection in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

Is there an easy and shortcut way to add a square selection to an existing selection? Normally to draw a square or circle selection one needs to hold the `Shift` key, but the `Shift` key is needed when adding to an exisiting selection. Is there any shortcut to preserve proportions when adding to a selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Use the 'Fixed Ratio' option in the top toolbar. Just type identical numbers in those two boxes and every new selection you make will be square without you having to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Works, thanks a lot.